# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI - Web API + Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api, routes

When I'm trying get some data with parameter (type `DateTime`) from Web API, I'm getting response  with error 404:

> Message
>   :
>   "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53544/api/reservations/GetReservationByDate?date=Tue Jan 31 2017 16:00:00 GMT+0100'."
>   MessageDetail
>   :
>   "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:53544/api/reservations/GetReservationByDate?date=Tue Jan 31 2017 16:00:00 GMT+0100'"

I'm using AngularJS for this. In others controllers, where I have method with parameter but neither DateTime. Is it maybe problem? Before this I had error

> 400 Bad Request

and configuration routing helps me.

It's all my code - method in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetReservationByDate")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Reservation))]
public IHttpActionResult GetReservationByDate(DateTime date)
{
    var reservation = db.Reservations.Where(d => d.Date.Equals(date));
    if (reservation == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(reservation);
}
```

RouteConfig.cs :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CustomApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/Reservations/GetReservationByDate/{date}",
    defaults: new { date = RouteParameter.Optional}
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and method from AngularJS:

```
this.GetReservation = function (date) {
    var promise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/reservations/GetReservationByDate?date=' + date,
        config: {
            params: {
                "date": date
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    function (response) {
        return response;
    });
    return promise;
}
```

I tried different combination, with `FromUri`, `FromBody`, but result always is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the defaults for controller and action since no template parameter is included in the route template.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CustomApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/Reservations/GetReservationByDate/{date}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Reservations", action = "GetReservationByDate", date = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

Update the action to allow for bad data

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetReservationByDate")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Reservation))]
public IHttpActionResult GetReservationByDate(DateTime? date) {    
    if(date.HasValue) {
        var reservation = db.Reservations.Where(d => d.Value.Date.Equals(date)).ToList();
        if (reservation.Count == 0) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(reservation);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Also try formatting the date client side to make sure it is being sent in the correct format

```
this.GetReservation = function (date) {
    var jsonDate = date.toJSON();
    var promise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/reservations/GetReservationByDate?date=' + jsonDate,
        config: {
            params: {
                "date": jsonDate
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    function (response) {
        return response;
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: I changed it like this, but then shows error 400 Bad Request: 
Message
:
"The request is invalid."
MessageDetail
:
"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'date' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetReservationByDate(System.DateTime)' in 'ServiceSchedule.Controllers.ReservationsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."

Comment: Right. I know what that means. Because the date parameter is optional it means that there is a possibility that no date could be provided (hence null) but the parameter in the action is non-nullable as it is a DateTime. Follow the instructions in the exception message `An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.`

Comment: And what is the solution? Change type of parameter..?

Comment: if you change type to `DateTime?` which is nullable DateTime it should work.

Comment: Yes, I did it before you answered me. It works, but now method always returns empty array

Comment: Check last update to answer. That just means that the query is not finding and result for the date provided. You should also debug the code to make sure you are sending a valid DateTime value.

Comment: Format of date in your javascript may not be compatible with .NET DateTime. If you are creating the date in javascript, then you can try accepting the date parameter as string. Then try DateTime.Parse to convert it to c# DateTime before passing it to the LINQ query

Comment: Value of date is always null. When I'm debugging, `date.HasValue` is always false

Comment: @ryckoshet, Then as mentioned by previous comment the date is not being sent in the correct format. It is hitting the action but the value being sent is not being parsed to a valid date time. Are you able to reformat the date in a format that can be parsed correctly. like yyyy-MM-dd for example.

Comment: I tried like this:
`DateTime dd = new DateTime();
            DateTime.TryParse(date.ToString(), out dd);`
But still is the same

Comment: @ryckoshet No, I think they meant `GetReservationByDate(string date)` and then parse that value.